# Mongo 3.2: Update All Array Elements That Match Condition

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I want a query to update `pmd` and `ed` for all `DEF` array if `isActive` is `true`, the positional operator is available from Mongo 3.6 onwards.

Can someone suggest something equivalent to positional operator in Mongo 3.2:

Document:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "_id" : "123456789",
        "globalId" : "00012345001"
    },
    "regionalAttributes" : {
        "CAD" : {
            "priceS" : "XYZ",
            "mdClusters" : {
                "DEF" : [ 
                    {
                        "cId" : "129",
                        "cName" : "815",
                        "pmd" : ISODate("2018-01-04T00:00:00.000Z"),
                        "ed" : ISODate("2018-04-15T00:00:00.000Z"),
                        "isActive" : false
                    }, 
                    {
                        "cId" : "193",
                        "cName" : "811",
                        "pmd" : ISODate("2019-06-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
                        "ed" : ISODate("2019-05-30T00:00:00.000Z"),
                        "isActive" : true
                    }, 
                    {
                        "cId" : "194",
                        "cName" : "812",
                        "pmd" : ISODate("2018-01-04T00:00:00.000Z"),
                        "ed" : ISODate("2018-04-15T00:00:00.000Z"),
                        "isActive" : true
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried elemMatch but it is updating only first matched array

```
 db.getCollection('items').updateMany(

    { "_id._id" : "123456789",{ "regionalAttributes.CAD.mdClusters.DEF": { "$elemMatch": {"isActive": true }} }},
    {"$set" : { "regionalAttributes.CAD.mdClusters.DEF.$.pmd" : ISODate("2019-05-29T00:00:00.000Z") , 
    "regionalAttributes.CAD.mdClusters.DEF.$.ed" : ISODate("2019-06-26T00:00:00.000Z")}});
```